# Converting 10 years of long-format transect data to wide-format

Tags: r

Despite lots of information on transformations of long format data to a wide format version, I am still stumped on how to get my dataset set up for analyses in an unmarked framework.  I have 20 lines of transect data repeated for each year-county combination, and I have not seen this format accounted for in previous posts.

Basically, I am trying to get from a format like this:

```
A   B   C   D
a   q   1   0
a   q   0   1
a   q   2   0
a   q   4   0
b   v   0   2
b   v   3   1
b   v   0   0
```

To a format like this:

```
A   B   C.1 C.2 C.3 C.4 D.1 D.2 D.3 D.4
a   q   1   0   2   4   0   1   0   0
b   v   0   3   3   0   2   1   4   0
```

I know it probably takes some combination of melt() and cast(), but what I can’t figure out is how to get the process to loop over a certain number of rows (4 in the example above, 20 in my real data).

Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Comment: At the moment it's unclear how the example input gets converted to the desired output. Can you take the time to fix your example so we can validate our code?

Comment: As BondedDust said, it's hard to tell exactly what you want with the example being off. This code gets me as close as I can to what you've shown:

    `Testmelt <- melt(Test, id.vars = c("A", "B"))`
    `dcast(Testmelt, A + B ~ variable+C+D)`

Comment: Or actually the data has 8 row?  Should insert into row 7 with "b v 3 4" for columns A, B, C, D?  This is pure speculation.

Answer (score 1):

I think the key piece of information that isn't in your original dataset is the observation number of each individual measurement (I'll call this variable `time`).  Without that, you don't have unique identifiers of each row and the reshaping tools won't work the way you wan them to.  Once you add that, you can use whatever reshaping tool you'd like to get the format you want.

Based on this dataset (with an extra row added based on your desired output)

```
  A B C D
1 a q 1 0
2 a q 0 1
3 a q 2 0
4 a q 4 0
5 b v 0 2
6 b v 3 1
7 b v 3 4
8 b v 0 0
```

The first thing to do is to add a *time* variable for each `A`/`B` combination.  I am using **dplyr** functions to add the time variable by group.  This assumes the dataset is already in the order of observations.  Then reshape, here with `melt` and `dcast` from **reshape2**.

```
library(reshape2)
library(dplyr)

dat %>%
    group_by(A, B) %>%
    mutate(time = 1:n()) %>%
    melt(id.vars = c("A", "B", "time")) %>%
    dcast(A + B ~ variable + time)
```

This is what the original dataset looks after adding the `time` variable:

```
Source: local data frame [8 x 5]
Groups: A, B

  A B C D time
1 a q 1 0    1
2 a q 0 1    2
3 a q 2 0    3
4 a q 4 0    4
5 b v 0 2    1
6 b v 3 1    2
7 b v 3 4    3
8 b v 0 0    4
```

Final output after reshaping:

```
  A B C_1 C_2 C_3 C_4 D_1 D_2 D_3 D_4
1 a q   1   0   2   4   0   1   0   0
2 b v   0   3   3   0   2   1   4   0
```

This gone be done with `gather` and `spread` from **tidyr**, but it took me an extra step of combining `time` with the C & D groups with `unite`.

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

dat %>%
group_by(A, B) %>%
mutate(time = 1:n()) %>%
gather(name, value, C:D) %>%
unite(Name, name, time, sep = ".", remove = TRUE) %>%
spread(Name, value)

  A B C.1 C.2 C.3 C.4 D.1 D.2 D.3 D.4
1 a q   1   0   2   4   0   1   0   0
2 b v   0   3   3   0   2   1   4   0
```